# Qlikview SQL query

Tags: sql, load, qlikview

New to Qlikview and I'm trying to merge columns from one table into a new table with fewer columns but more rows e.g.

What is the best option for this?
Any help appreciated[image]

Comment: Please provide more info about the problem.

Comment: Hi. I can load a table with 8 columns and 1 row, as per first part of the diagram but ideally would like to load it as 4 columns with 3 rows of data like to lower part of the diagram

Comment: Crosstable function might work, but the structure is not ideal.. Maybe if you can have the data in the format of Name, Date, Text1|Value1, Text2|Value2, ..., TextN|ValueN and use subfield(Data, '|', 1) as Text after a crosstable load... maybe..

Comment: Thx - I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve your problem is via a loop in your script. See the following example:

```
//input table
table:
load * Inline [
n, d, t1, v1, t2, v2, t3, v3
Bob, 07-jul, a, 1, b, 2, c, 3
];

//Use dummy field to setup result table.
result:
Load * Inline [DUMMY];

//Set starting position.
set k=3;

do WHILE k <= NoOfFields('table')

    //result table need to exist pre loop.
    Concatenate(result) Load
        n as name,
        d as date,          
        peek(FieldName($(k),'table'),0,'table') as text,
        peek(FieldName($(k)+1,'table'),0,'table') as value          
    resident table;     

    let k = $(k)+2;

loop    

drop field DUMMY;
```